# Rails Media Queries for Background Images with Dynamic Image Paths (Paperclip)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, media-queries, spree

I'm making a banner slider that is populated with the latest four blog entries from the site's blog section. Each blog entry has an associated image, and this associated image acts as the background image for the banner. For instance, `background-image: url('<%= blog_entry.blog_entry_image.attachment.url(:banner_full) %>');` (This must remain a background image, since I need to style it with `background-position: center` to get the desired position on resize.) This all works lovely.

Then I tried to make those background images adaptive/responsive. **The problem is that whichever image came last is served for all of the following blog entries in the banner slider.**

Here's what the banner looks like:

```
<div class="index_banner">
            <div class="bx-wrapper" style="max-width: 100%;"><div class="bx-viewport" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; position: relative; height: 340px;"><ul id="blog_entry_entries" class="bxslider" style="width: 415%; position: relative; -webkit-transition: 0s; transition: 0s; -webkit-transform: translate3d(-2086px, 0, 0);"><li style="float: left; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 1043px;" class="bx-clone">
                  <div class="banner_image">
  <style type="text/css">
    .banner_image {
      height: 300px;
      width: 100%;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-image: url('/assets/blog_entry_images/1/banner_full/2638414-e2e60f86b94891c2b3276f8181dc714f877149b9.jpg?1408455094');
      background-size: 1400px 300px;
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
      .banner_image {
        background-image: url('/assets/blog_entry_images/1/banner_large/2638414-e2e60f86b94891c2b3276f8181dc714f877149b9.jpg?1408455094');
        background-size: 1024px 300px;
      }
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      .banner_image {
        background-image: url('/assets/blog_entry_images/1/banner_medium/2638414-e2e60f86b94891c2b3276f8181dc714f877149b9.jpg?1408455094');
        background-size: 768px 300px;
      }
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 568px) {
      .banner_image {
        height: 240px;
        background-image: url('/assets/blog_entry_images/1/banner_small/2638414-e2e60f86b94891c2b3276f8181dc714f877149b9.jpg?1408455094');
        background-size: 568px 240px;
      }
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
      .banner_image {
        height: 240px;
        background-image: url('/assets/blog_entry_images/1/banner_mini/2638414-e2e60f86b94891c2b3276f8181dc714f877149b9.jpg?1408455094');
        background-size: 480px 240px;
      }
    }
  </style>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="columns sixteen blog_content">
      <h2 class="banner_title"><a href="/blog/2014/08/17/asdf">Test Post #1</a></h2>

      <div class="blog_entry_summary">
        This is the first test post.
        <span class="blog_read_more"><a href="/blog/2014/08/17/asdf">Read more</a></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

                </li>
                <li style="float: left; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 1043px;">
                  <div class="banner_image">
  <style type="text/css">
    .banner_image {
      height: 300px;
      width: 100%;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-image: url('/assets/blog_entry_images/2/banner_full/messiaen.jpg?1408455033');
      background-size: 1400px 300px;
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
      .banner_image {
        background-image: url('/assets/blog_entry_images/2/banner_large/messiaen.jpg?1408455033');
        background-size: 1024px 300px;
      }
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      .banner_image {
        background-image: url('/assets/blog_entry_images/2/banner_medium/messiaen.jpg?1408455033');
        background-size: 768px 300px;
      }
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 568px) {
      .banner_image {
        height: 240px;
        background-image: url('/assets/blog_entry_images/2/banner_small/messiaen.jpg?1408455033');
        background-size: 568px 240px;
      }
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
      .banner_image {
        height: 240px;
        background-image: url('/assets/blog_entry_images/2/banner_mini/messiaen.jpg?1408455033');
        background-size: 480px 240px;
      }
    }
  </style>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="columns sixteen blog_content">
      <h2 class="banner_title"><a href="/blog/2014/08/18/123">Test Post #2</a></h2>

      <div class="blog_entry_summary">
        This is the second post.
        <span class="blog_read_more"><a href="/blog/2014/08/18/123">Read more</a></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

                </li>
                <li style="float: left; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 1043px;">
                  <div class="banner_image">
  <style type="text/css">
    .banner_image {
      height: 300px;
      width: 100%;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-image: url('/assets/blog_entry_images/1/banner_full/2638414-e2e60f86b94891c2b3276f8181dc714f877149b9.jpg?1408455094');
      background-size: 1400px 300px;
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
      .banner_image {
        background-image: url('/assets/blog_entry_images/1/banner_large/2638414-e2e60f86b94891c2b3276f8181dc714f877149b9.jpg?1408455094');
        background-size: 1024px 300px;
      }
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      .banner_image {
        background-image: url('/assets/blog_entry_images/1/banner_medium/2638414-e2e60f86b94891c2b3276f8181dc714f877149b9.jpg?1408455094');
        background-size: 768px 300px;
      }
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 568px) {
      .banner_image {
        height: 240px;
        background-image: url('/assets/blog_entry_images/1/banner_small/2638414-e2e60f86b94891c2b3276f8181dc714f877149b9.jpg?1408455094');
        background-size: 568px 240px;
      }
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
      .banner_image {
        height: 240px;
        background-image: url('/assets/blog_entry_images/1/banner_mini/2638414-e2e60f86b94891c2b3276f8181dc714f877149b9.jpg?1408455094');
        background-size: 480px 240px;
      }
    }
  </style>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="columns sixteen blog_content">
      <h2 class="banner_title"><a href="/blog/2014/08/17/asdf">Test Post #1</a></h2>

      <div class="blog_entry_summary">
        This is the first test post.
        <span class="blog_read_more"><a href="/blog/2014/08/17/asdf">Read more</a></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

                </li>
            <li style="float: left; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 1043px;" class="bx-clone">
                  <div class="banner_image">
  <style type="text/css">
    .banner_image {
      height: 300px;
      width: 100%;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-image: url('/assets/blog_entry_images/2/banner_full/messiaen.jpg?1408455033');
      background-size: 1400px 300px;
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
      .banner_image {
        background-image: url('/assets/blog_entry_images/2/banner_large/messiaen.jpg?1408455033');
        background-size: 1024px 300px;
      }
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      .banner_image {
        background-image: url('/assets/blog_entry_images/2/banner_medium/messiaen.jpg?1408455033');
        background-size: 768px 300px;
      }
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 568px) {
      .banner_image {
        height: 240px;
        background-image: url('/assets/blog_entry_images/2/banner_small/messiaen.jpg?1408455033');
        background-size: 568px 240px;
      }
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
      .banner_image {
        height: 240px;
        background-image: url('/assets/blog_entry_images/2/banner_mini/messiaen.jpg?1408455033');
        background-size: 480px 240px;
      }
    }
  </style>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="columns sixteen blog_content">
      <h2 class="banner_title"><a href="/blog/2014/08/18/123">Test Post #2</a></h2>

      <div class="blog_entry_summary">
        This is the second post.
        <span class="blog_read_more"><a href="/blog/2014/08/18/123">Read more</a></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

                </li></ul></div><div class="bx-controls bx-has-pager bx-has-controls-direction"><div class="bx-pager bx-default-pager"><div class="bx-pager-item"><a href="" data-slide-index="0" class="bx-pager-link">1</a></div><div class="bx-pager-item"><a href="" data-slide-index="1" class="bx-pager-link active">2</a></div></div><div class="bx-controls-direction"><a class="bx-prev" href="">Prev</a><a class="bx-next" href="">Next</a></div></div></div>
          </div>
```

Here's what I have for paperclip:

```
class Spree::BlogEntryImage < Spree::Image
  has_attached_file :attachment,
     :styles => {
       :mini => '96x96#',
       :normal => '400x400#',
       :banner_mini =>     ['480x240#',       :jpg, :quality => 80],
       :banner_small =>    ['568x240#',       :jpg, :quality => 80],
       :banner_medium =>   ['768x300#',       :jpg, :quality => 80],
       :banner_large =>    ['1024x300#',      :jpg, :quality => 80],
       :banner_full =>     ['1400x300>',      :jpg, :quality => 80],
       :banner_mini2x =>   ['960x480#',       :jpg, :quality => 60],
       :banner_small2x =>  ['1536x600#',      :jpg, :quality => 60],
       :banner_medium2x => ['2048x600#',      :jpg, :quality => 60],
       :banner_large2x =>  ['2048x600#',      :jpg, :quality => 60],
       :banner_full2x =>   ['2800x600>',      :jpg, :quality => 60]
     },
     :convert_options => {
       :banner_mini2x => '-set colorspace sRGB -strip -sharpen 0x0.5',
       :banner_small2x => '-set colorspace sRGB -strip -sharpen 0x0.5',
       :banner_medium2x => '-set colorspace sRGB -strip -sharpen 0x0.5',
       :banner_large2x => '-set colorspace sRGB -strip -sharpen 0x0.5',
       :banner_full2x => '-set colorspace sRGB -strip -sharpen 0x0.5'
     },
     :default_style => :banner_large,
     :url => "/assets/blog_entry_images/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
     :path => ":rails_root/public/assets/blog_entry_images/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
end
```

For each blog post, it renders the partial in this way:

```
    <% if !@blog_entries.empty? %>
      <div class='index_banner'>
        <ul id='blog_entry_entries' class='bxslider'>
          <% @blog_entries.each do |blog_entry| %>
            <li>
              <%= render :partial => 'spree/blog_entries/index_blog_banner', :locals => {:blog_entry => blog_entry} %>
            </li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    <% else %>
      <p id='no_entries'><%= Spree.t(:no_blog_entries) %></p>
    <% end %>
```

My approach has been to set the background image in a `<style>` tag in the view as such:

```
<div class="banner_image">
  <style type="text/css">
    .banner_image {
      height: 300px;
      width: 100%;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-image: url('<%= blog_entry.blog_entry_image.attachment.url(:banner_full) %>');
      background-size: 1400px 300px;
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
      .banner_image {
        background-image: url('<%= blog_entry.blog_entry_image.attachment.url(:banner_large) %>');
        background-size: 1024px 300px;
      }
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      .banner_image {
        background-image: url('<%= blog_entry.blog_entry_image.attachment.url(:banner_medium) %>');
        background-size: 768px 300px;
      }
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 568px) {
      .banner_image {
        height: 240px;
        background-image: url('<%= blog_entry.blog_entry_image.attachment.url(:banner_small) %>');
        background-size: 568px 240px;
      }
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
      .banner_image {
        height: 240px;
        background-image: url('<%= blog_entry.blog_entry_image.attachment.url(:banner_mini) %>');
        background-size: 480px 240px;
      }
    }
  </style>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="columns sixteen blog_content">
      <h2 class="banner_title"><%= link_to blog_entry.title, blog_entry_permalink(blog_entry) %></h2>

      <div class="blog_entry_summary">
        <%== blog_entry.entry_summary %>
        <span class="blog_read_more"><%= link_to Spree.t(:blog_read_more), blog_entry_permalink(blog_entry) %></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I keep the last loaded image from being used on all blog posts in the banner?

Comment: Keep what from happening? You dumped a lot of code but you neither show expected result nor actual result.

Comment: @MichalSzyndel, I added some pictures and explained a little more. I want all blog posts to use their associated image as the background. I do not want all posts to use the image associated with the last loaded blog post.

Comment: Could you please get rid of those images and include some CODE? Hopefully with both posts in one excerpt.

Comment: I think that's what you want?

Comment: Nevermind! I made a stupid mistake – forgot to make the class name dynamic. Will post as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just found what I overlooked! I'll post it here in case anyone else makes the same mistake. All that had to be done was make the class name dynamic. The following method worked, but there's probably a more efficient way to do this.

```
<div class="banner_image_<%= blog_entry.attributes['id'] %>">
  <style type="text/css">
    .banner_image_<%= blog_entry.attributes['id'] %> {
      height: 300px;
      width: 100%;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-image: url('<%= blog_entry.blog_entry_image.attachment.url(:banner_full) %>');
      background-size: 1400px 300px;
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
      .banner_image_<%= blog_entry.attributes['id'] %> {
        background-image: url('<%= blog_entry.blog_entry_image.attachment.url(:banner_large) %>');
        background-size: 1024px 300px;
      }
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      .banner_image_<%= blog_entry.attributes['id'] %> {
        background-image: url('<%= blog_entry.blog_entry_image.attachment.url(:banner_medium) %>');
        background-size: 768px 300px;
      }
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 568px) {
      .banner_image_<%= blog_entry.attributes['id'] %> {
        height: 240px;
        background-image: url('<%= blog_entry.blog_entry_image.attachment.url(:banner_small) %>');
        background-size: 568px 240px;
      }
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
      .banner_image_<%= blog_entry.attributes['id'] %> {
        height: 240px;
        background-image: url('<%= blog_entry.blog_entry_image.attachment.url(:banner_mini) %>');
        background-size: 480px 240px;
      }
    }
  </style>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="columns sixteen blog_content">
      <h2 class="banner_title"><%= link_to blog_entry.title, blog_entry_permalink(blog_entry) %></h2>

      <div class="blog_entry_summary">
        <%== blog_entry.entry_summary %>
        <span class="blog_read_more"><%= link_to Spree.t(:blog_read_more), blog_entry_permalink(blog_entry) %></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```